# Given 2 possible outcomes (i.e win or lose) can both happen "often"?

Tags: meaning

I was wondering, whether or not out of 2 possibilities, if *both* can happen "often".
By definition often means "many times" or "frequently". Does this mean that often has to happen relative to something else? Or is it some number that happens often.

For example, if someone plays 500 games, wins 250, loses 250 can both be considered to happen "often"?

Thanks!

Comment: You got that right. _Often_ is a vague term. In the film Annie Hall, a man and woman complain separately to their therapists that they have sex "too frequently" and "too infrequently," referring, as is happens, to the same frequency. Same with 'often,' in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Yeah, depends on what you mean by "often". It may imply 80%, may imply 8%.  Depends on the context (and the prejudices of the author and reader).

Comment: It usually rains in October in the bay area but some years it doesn't. If often rains once in May.

Comment: In my mind "often" is less than 50% but means "good chance it might happen"

Comment: I can imagine a baseball player near the end of the season saying, "We won often, and we lost often.  But we lost more often than we won.  So here we are in the bottom half . . ."

Comment: The frequency required to constitute a happening as *often* will depend to some extent on its relation to an expected frequency. For example four eruptions of a volcano in 100 years might be "often", if it had only erupted once in the previous 1000 years. However a football team which only scored four goals in 100 years would not be scoring often enough for most of its fans' (if it still had any) liking!